# Prevent Oculus home from starting automatically once my android device is plugged in Gear VR

Tags: android, oculus, gear-vr

I am facing a problem while running my android app on Gear VR Oculus. I start my app and launch the 360 video. Once I plug the phone into the Gear headset, it automatically enters the Oculus home and my app is not active anymore.

I have configured the phone with Oculus Signature file and also enabled Oculus developer mode, so what is the problem ?

How can I prevent Oculus home from launching and blocking my app?